# kvm Error starting domain: unsupported configuration: Unable to find security driver for model selinux

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtual-host, libvirt, virsh

Trying to start our kvm virtual machines and getting this error after rebooting the physical host machine.

```
Error starting domain: unsupported configuration: Unable to find security driver for model selinux

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 88, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 124, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/libvirtobject.py", line 83, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/domain.py", line 1479, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 1062, in create
    if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreate() failed', dom=self)
libvirtError: unsupported configuration: Unable to find security driver for model selinux
```

Checkin the host machine shows us that Selinux is disabled.

```
$ getenforce 
Disabled
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the virtual machines backup and running

I ran the following, to edit the domain xml config file.

```
$ virsh edit some-virtual-machine / domain
```

Remove the following line, which was near the boot of the virtual machine domain definition xml.

```
<seclabel type='dynamic' model='selinux' relabel='yes'/>
```

That gets the virtual machines up and running.

You could also edit the configs in the libvirt config directory before trying to boot the virtual machines. `/etc/libvirt/qemu/`

Comment: Excuse me, do I need to restart anything if I modify the content of `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf`?

Comment: I found the answer, restart `libvirtd` after modifying `qemu.conf` is a must.